# Contar los Elementos de una Lista Agrupada Omitiendo un Valor Determinado

Tags: python

Teniendo una lista agrupada:

```
despachoAsignado = [(1, [54, 35, 50, 0, 33, 35, 42, 33, 36]), (2, [0, 48, 48]), (3, [35, 52, 55, 34, 54, 39]), (4, [0, 0, 0, 54, 36, 40, 50]), (5, [0, 44, 35, 37, 32])]
```

Necesitaba contar los elementos de la sublista i[1], generando otra lista como la siguiente:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 5)]
```

Como se puede observar, el resultado de esta lista cuenta todos los valores agrupados.

Gracias a la gran ayuda de Patricio Moracho pude obtener el resultado que necesitaba con el siguiente código:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(i[0], len(i[1])) for i in despachoAsignado]
print(totalDespachoAsignado)

[(1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 5)]
```

Ahora me surge otro requisito adicional, el cual indica que debo realizar el conteo sin tener en cuenta los ceros "0", es decir que la lista que necesito debe salir de la siguiente manera:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(1, 8), (2, 2), (3, 6), (4, 4), (5, 4)]
```

Como se puede observar en la nueva lista no se tienen en cuenta los ceros al momento del conteo.

He intentado de varias maneras y no he podido lograrlo, el código que mas se ha acercado es el siguiente:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(i[0], len(i[1]) - len(i[1]) == 0) for i in despachoAsignadoAgrupado]
```

que me da una salida como la siguiente:

```
[(1, True), (2, True), (3, True), (4, True), (5, True)]
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener un conteo de los valores de una lista agrupada que no tenga en cuenta un valor "n" en el conteo y me devuelva una lista como la que necesito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una solución es usar una *list comprehension* con filtro (con un `if` al final) para que genere la lista sin los ceros y así contar la longitud de ésta. Para que el código quede más legible se puede escribir una función que haga esto, que sería así:

```
def sin_ceros(lista):
    return [x for x in lista if x != 0]
```

Haciendo uso de esta función, la línea que te calcula lo que buscabas quedaría así:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(i[0], len(sin_ceros(i[1])) for i in despachoAsignadoAgrupado]
```

### Bonus

Para hacerlo más general la función `sin_ceros()` podría recibir otro parámetro que sea el valor a eliminar, por si en el futuro te piden quitar los unos o lo que sea:

```
def quitar_valor(lista, valor):
   return [x for x in lista if x != valor]
```

Otra ligera mejora es la expresión para la compresión de listas que usas al final. Para evitar tener que acceder a `i[0]`, `i[1]`, que es poco legible, puedes desempaquetar cada elemento de `despachoAsignadoAgrupado` en dos variables que podemos llamar `indice` y `lista` respectivamente. Entonces te quedaría así:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(indice, len(quitar_valor(lista, 0)) 
                          for indice, lista in despachoAsignadoAgrupado]
```

Creo que esto mejora la legibilidad del código, lo cual es importante para mejorar también la mantenibilidad (que quien lo lea después porque haya que cambiar algo, aunque seas tú mismo unas semanas más tarde, pueda comprender más fácilmente lo que hace el código).

### Bonus 2 ¿por qué no funcionaba tu intento?

Habías escrito:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(i[0], len(i[1]) - len(i[1]) == 0) 
                         for i in despachoAsignadoAgrupado]
```

Fijémonos en la expresión:

```
len(i[1]) - len(i[1]) == 0
```

Dada la precedencia de los operadores en python, ya que `==` es el que menos prioridad tiene, la expresión equivale a la siguiente, en la que he puesto paréntesis para dejar más claro el orden de evaluación:

```
(len(i[1]) - len(i[1])) == 0
```

Vamos, que primero hace la resta, la cual le va a salir obviamente cero pues estás restando el mismo valor, y luego la comparación. El resultado es el booleano `True`, ya que la comparación `0 == 0` es cierta. ¡No es de extrañar que te salieran todos esos `True`!

Entiendo que quizás lo que querías decir era algo como:

```
len(i[1]) - len(i[1] == 0)
```

con la esperanza de que `(i[1] == 0)` te devolviera de alguna forma una lista que contuviera sólo los ceros. Por desgracia no es eso lo que hace esta expresión. Simplemente compara con `0` el valor de `i[i]`. La comparación dará un error porque `i[1]` es una lista, pero 0 es un entero. No se puede comparar una lista con un entero.

Un enfoque para lograr lo que tú buscabas sería utilizar el método `.count()`  de las listas. Así `lista.count(0)` te devolvería cuántas veces aparece el 0 en esa lista. Usando esta idea podrías haber escrito:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(i[0], len(i[1]) - i[1].count(0)) 
                          for i in despachoAsignadoAgrupado]
```

Comment: Impecable... abulafia te agradezco mucho tu explicación que enriquece tu respuesta. Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y vieras lo mucho que aprendo con Uds., de nuevo gracias a ti y a todos los que sacan un poco de su tiempo para ayudar a los demás.